# Aligning Favourite button in AppBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout

I create this detail screen

[image: Detail Activity]

I want to move app the favorite button like

[image]

This is my code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/photo_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detail_image_view"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_broken_image"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_height="350dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_title"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Recent News"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/detail_publish_date"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fav_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />
```

How can I do that?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Remove **`android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"`** from your **`FloatingActionButton`** it will work

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/photo_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title=""
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/detail_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/kid_goku"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="@string/app_name" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Recent News"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="12dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/detail_publish_date"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="TextView" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fav_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]